How do I visualise an lmer model adjusted for covariates using ggplot?
I'm trying to visualise my adjusted lmer model showing an interaction of education status using the predict function and ggplot, but I get a zig-zag output when I add in my covariates. I want to include 95% CI bands as well.
I managed to plot my unadjusted model using the following code:
Unadjusted Model
lmer3<- lmer(outcome~time_years*educ+ before_after*educ+ 
    time_since_job*educ + (1 | pidp), data = dat)
summary(lmer3) 

predictions <- predict(lmer3, newdata = dat, re.form = NA, 
    type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)
dat$predicted_values <- predictions$fit
# Getting 95% CI bands
dat$lower_bound <- dat$predicted_values - 1.96 * dat$se_predicted
dat$upper_bound <- dat$predicted_values + 1.96 * dat$se_predicted

GGplot Code
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time_years, y = predicted_values,
     color = as.factor(educ))) +
  theme_classic()+
    geom_line() + ##line showing predicted values from model 
    labs(x = "Time (years)", 
     y = "Daily MET-min", color = "Education ") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_bound , ymax = upper_bound), alpha = 0.3, linetype= 0,fill = "grey")+
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), label=c("No Degree", "Degree or higher")) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0,linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
      labs(x = "Time relative to job start (years)", y = "Daily Exercise", color = "Education Status")


But when I add in my covariates, I get a messy and nonsensical graph:
Adjusted Model
lmer4 <- lmer(outcome~time_years*educ+ before_after*educ+ 
    time_since_job*educ + sex_dv + ethnicity + parentEducation + 
     (1 | pidp), data = dat)
summary(lmer4)

predictions <- predict(lmer4, newdata = dat, re.form = NA, 
    type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)


I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

FYI, the marginaleffects package can plot these model results and return a ggplot2 object. See these two links for relevant examples: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/plot.html   https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/lme4.html

What exactly do you want the resulting plot to look like? Most graphs are very limited in the number of variables you can show at once. You have an x axis, y axis, and color. You don't really have any more dimensions to show more variables unless you make some sort of simplifying assumptions. If you want general data visualization advice, that's off topic here and might be more appropriate for [stats.se] instead.
